# VS code autocomplete for import from nested node module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a folder structure as follows setup with a typescript project:

```
Project root
 -node_modules
   -@moduleA
     -node_modules
       -@moduleB
```

For further reasons in do not want to install module B directly into the node modules of the project root.

I can import something from moduleB just fine using an import as follows:

```
import { foo } from "@moduleA/node_modules/@moduleB/foo
```

However vs code does not suggest this import or autocomplete this import for me when i start typing "import foo" or "foo"

Is there a way to extend the scope of the autocomplete of VS code to allow autocomplete in such a nested structure?